# Sequelize - set foreign key of child when saving parent

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, sequelize-typescript

i'm using Sequelize 5. I have problem saving a parent with a child when the child is not present when parent was fetched from the DB.

My code:

```
  const parent: Parent = await Parent.schema(tenant).findByPk<Parent>(parentId, { include: relations });
  parent.update({
    medizinischeAngaben: 'This works',
    hochbegabung: 'Also works'
  });
  parent.person.update({
    name: 'This works'
  });
  if ( parent.child === null) {
    const newChild: Child = await Child.schema(tenant).create({name: 'CHILD_NAME'});
    parent.child = newChild;
    parent.save();
  }
  parent.child.update({
    name: 'Name from Frontend'
  });
  parent.save();
```

It saves the data on the Parent (lines 3 and 4). 
When a child property like person exists then the update also works - line 7. 
Then i got a child which might be null. Im checking for it in the if. I create a new child. It is saved to the DB. Then i try to associate to the parent and save the parent.

I expect that the foreign key id_child is set on the parent, but it does not happen.

Funny thing is: when i later update the name of the child with the Name from the Frontend this also correctly is save to the DB.

How do i save the association on the Parent correctly?

Database is PostgreSQL

Answer (score 0):

If the primary key of Child is an auto_increment, Sequelize doesn't retrieve this value from the database (check it out in the debugger). Thus the line `parent.child = newChild;` is actually setting the foreign key to null.

You might try `options.returning : true` on the create statement - it's for Postgres only and **seems** like it should make your code work.  I use MySql, for which there is no such option and you'd have to SELECT the newly inserted row before associating with the parent.